# sum of a complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have to find the sum of a complex power series inside radius of convergence, for simplicity let's say the series looks something like that:

$f(z)=\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{z^n}{n(n-1)}$

Then after derivating twice:

$f(z)^{''}=\sum_{n \geq 2} z^{n-2}=\frac{1}{1-z}$ integrating once I get $f(z)^{'}=-\log(1-z) $ then integrating by parts I get $f(z)=(1-z)\log(1-z)+z$.

Because the sum starts at $n=2$ I considered the integration constants equal to 0, since no term is lost derivating, is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at it another way.  Note that

$$\frac1{n (n-1)} = \frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n}$$

so that

$$\begin{align}f(z) &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n-1} - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\\ &= z \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n-1}}{n-1}- \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\\ &= z \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n}- \left (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n} - z\right ) \\ &= z+\log{(1-z)} - z \log{(1-z)} \\ &= z+(1-z) \log{(1-z)}\end{align}$$